# TableName.RowName retrieves Nothing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model class called "KelimeTuru" designed as shown below:

```
public partial class KelimeTuru
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int KelimeId { get; set; }
        public int MenseiId { get; set; }
        public int TurId { get; set; }
        public int AnlamTurleriId { get; set; }
        public int SozlukTuruId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SesId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VideoId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ResimId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SembolId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BirimId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SimgeId { get; set; }
        public string Anlam { get; set; }
        public string Transkript { get; set; }

        public virtual AnlamTurleri AnlamTurleri { get; set; }
        public virtual Birim Birim { get; set; }
        public virtual Kelime Kelime { get; set; }
        public virtual Mensei Mensei { get; set; }
        public virtual Sembol Sembol { get; set; }
        public virtual Ses Ses { get; set; }
        public virtual Simge Simge { get; set; }
        public virtual SozlukTuru SozlukTuru { get; set; }
        public virtual Turler Turler { get; set; }
        public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
        public virtual Resim Resim { get; set; }
    }
```

And It retrieves the required data if we use the **Id** of the record properly like this:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id=0)
        {
            SozlukEntities db = new SozlukEntities();
            KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Find(id);

            if (kelime == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(kelime);
        }
```

I want to retrieve records according to their "KelimeId"s not "Id"s so replaced the word "id" with "KelimeId" in my code. But got a "404.0 - Not Found" error.
**Could you please help me retrieve "KelimeTuru" table using KelimeId?**

Comment: it means the KelimeId which you are passing, record is not against it in database

Comment: But I have the record with that KelimeId in the table

Comment: how details will be called ? calling through Ajax ? could you please update more details ?

Comment: like this : http://localhost:52278/Home/Details/2 (I am sure I got a record with KelimeId 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.SingleOrDefault(x => x.KelimeId == id);
```

Find method works only on Primary Key Property, means if your property is decorated with `[Key]` attribute, then `Find()` will be able to find record, otherwise it wil not fetch the record.

Comment: Ehsan you're an awesome man, you know that? :)
Thanks again,that fixed !

Comment: @Ehsan why KelimeId parameter not working in action ?

Comment: its not working with Find, i doubt not sure that Find searches with Primary key

Comment: @Ehsan i thought its related to routing problem. default "id" argument will be there in route table.kelimeid is not there that why its throwing error..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
KelimeTuru kelime = db.KelimeTuru.Where(x => x.KelimeId == id).SingleOrDefault();
```